# Android - Realm not getting object inside a model > EDIT Not getting Realm Object inside a Realm Object

Tags: android, realm

I have a model, say `PostModel` and another model which stores PostModel's id and date when it was created.

```
public class RealmPostModel extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private PostModel postModel;
}

public class PostModel extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    public int post_id;
}
```

And what I do to save (I do this in `onPause`) is :

```
    MIApplication.realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmPostModel singlePostModelRealmResults = MIApplication.realm.where(RealmPostModel.class)
            .equalTo("id", Integer.valueOf(clickedPostId)).findFirst();

    if (singlePostModelRealmResults != null){
        singlePostModelRealmResults.deleteFromRealm();
    }

    RealmPostModel realmSinglePostModel = new RealmPostModel(Integer.valueOf(clickedPostId),
            new Date(),
            new PostModel(singlePostAdapter.getmDataset()));
    // Here, realmSinglePostModel shows that it has PostModel
    // and not null
    MIApplication.realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(realmSinglePostModel);
    MIApplication.realm.commitTransaction();
```

And to access it back (I do this in `onViewCreated`) is :

```
    MIApplication.realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmPostModel singlePostModelRealmResults = MIApplication.realm.where(RealmPostModel.class)
            .equalTo("id", Integer.valueOf(clickedPostId)).findFirst();
    MIApplication.realm.commitTransaction();
    // Here singlePostModelRealmResults shows that PostModel is null inside
    // RealmPostModel where id is clickedPostId
```

Problem is, the `PostModel` object inside `RealmPostModel` object always null when I retrieve it. Am I actually doing `Realm` wrong?

EDIT :

[image: PostModel added]
Here, `postModel:PostModel`. But when I do `ctrl+f1` to check the details, it says that PostModel is null. But it's a false positive right as said in the documentation.

[image: Here PostModel is null]
Here, `PostModel` is null when I retrieve it from the table.

I actually have an alternative to just to use the `RealmPostModel` id as a foreign key to `PostModel` as they are the same. For convenience, I did what I did (`RealmPostModel` have 3 columns, one points to `PostModel`).

Comment: 1.) why are you beginning/committing a transaction on the UI thread synchronously just to evaluate a query and 2.) `onViewCreated()` is not necessarily called after `onPause()`. The pair of `onPause()` is `onResume()`. and 3.) why are you writing the same object twice :o

Comment: I think you have to save `PostModel` first before adding it to `RealmPostModel` object. So first do `PostModel model = ...` then `MIApplication.realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(model);` and then create `RealmPostModel` object with `model` as third parameter.

Comment: 1. So I have to run it async in this kind of situation?! My whole life is a lie! 2. Um it's for `FragmentTransaction` management, every `onPause` it saves so when user presses back, the data will still be available 3. Damn, it was a copy paste error, I got several other codes in between and it got mixed up

Comment: Will check the solution you mentioned, be right back in several mins as my app needs 2 mins every compile and install ._.

Comment: Why do you think it is `null`? Could it be this problem? https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging

Comment: @beeender It might be the problem! I didn't read that! lol. I shall make an accessor to try it, and if it is actually not null, I've been doing some useless stuffs -.-

Comment: @beeender Hmm too bad but it doesn't work.. It is actually null in there, but, when I save the `RealmPostModel` in `onPause`, the actual `PostModel` gets updated too, it's just I can't get it to connect with `RealmPostModel`

Comment: @KevinMurvie would you please update the question with where did you get the null value, and the source code of the three params constructor of `RealmPostModel`?

Comment: @beeender The source code for `RealmPostModel` is presented, the rest of the lines are basic getter and setter, are those essential as well?

Comment: I am running out of ideas. Can you try to check the query results right after `copyToRealmOrUpdate` called? Also please remember `copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj)` returns a managed RealmObject which is different from obj. If it still has problems, you can send the project to help@realm.io and i will take a look. thanks.

Comment: Ah I didn't even try to check the return of `copyToRealmOrUpdate`, I'm checking it now, gotta need several mins as I am working on another thing and I actually changed `RealmPostModel` to have only 2 params just the id and date, gotta revert those